# Scala huffman decoding

Tags: scala, decoding, huffman-code

I am doing the scala coursera course and trying to write an implementation for the 'decode' method of the huffman algorithm. I am new to scala.

Following is my code(so far).

```
def decode(tree: CodeTree, bits: List[Bit]): List[Char] = {

def innerDecode(subTree: CodeTree, subBits: List[Bit]): List[Char] =
 subBits match {
  case head :: rest => {
    subTree match {
      case Leaf(c, w) => c :: innerDecode(tree, rest)
      case Fork(left, right, _, _) => {
        if ( head == 0) innerDecode(left, rest)
        else  innerDecode(right, rest)
     }
    }
   }
  case Nil => List[Char]()
 }
innerDecode(tree, bits)
}
```

When writing a test e.g. below:

```
  val decoded = decode(t1, List(0, 1))
  assert(decoded === List('a','b'))//  decoded is returned as List('a') instead of List('a','b')
```

Gives `t1` as: `Fork(Leaf('a',2), Leaf('b',3), List('a','b'), 5)`
Can someone please advise why the implementation will return just `List('a')`
The encode for `aabbb` I assume is:

```
a -> 0
b -> 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Huffman decoding you take one bit of `subBits` each time you fork, go right or left.  In your implementation you do this when you fork and when you reach a `Leaf`.  Each time you reach a letter you throw one additional bit away.

You could see that with few more tests, in your case:

```
decode(List(0,1)) === List(a)
decode(List(0,0,1)) === List(a,b)
decode(List(0,0,0)) === List(a,a)
decode(List(0,1,0)) === List(a,a)
```

Or you could use debugger and go trough execution of your code step by step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes that was the problem. I really shouldn't have used the bit when reaching the leaf. Also there was a slight problem with the head:: rest which was falling to the 'Nil' part when the last character was reached so was overlooking the cases. Had to do an extra check in the 'Case Fork' part for the very last element. Partly my misunderstanding of how the pattern matching works with the linked lists.